# Deny access to built-in camera on MacBook Pro for some applications

Tags: macos, mac, camera, privacy, webex

I am using the WebEx screen-sharing/online meeting software on a MacBook Pro.
When active, it grabs control of the built-in video camera, even though all I want to do is screen-sharing. This even happens when I am just watching other people's screens (and not sharing anything myself).

Since the application itself seems to have no setting regarding the video camera, is there a way to selectively disable access to the camera from the OS?

Or alternatively, a master switch to disable the camera altogether?

Comment: FWIW, WebEx has seen the light and now includes in-app controls for the camera.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to put a small piece of masking tape over the iSight camera.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing. Another problem though is that while WebEx has control of the camera, I cannot use it for iChat or Skype, which I may actually want to.

Comment: Or at least make sure to wear a pair of pants.

Comment: Definitely wear a pair of pants.

Answer (score 0):

One method of disabling the built-in iSight is to remove the component necessary to translate the signal into anything useable:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component /PATH/TO/SAFE/DIRECTORY/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component
```

Replace /PATH/TO/SAFE/DIRECTORY with the path to a folder that you want to move the component to.

When you want access back move the component back:

```
sudo mv /PATH/TO/SAFE/DIRECTORY/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component
```

The other alternative is to change the permissions (`chmod a-rwx` to disable, `chmod a+r` to re-enable) on `/System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer`.

Comment: Would that require a reboot?